# How to convert backslash string to forward slash string in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, os.path, pathlib

I am using python3 in my ubuntu machine.
I have a string variable which consist a path with backslash and i need to convert it to forward slash string. So i tried

```
import pathlib
s = '\dir\wnotherdir\joodir\more'
x = repr(s)
p = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(x)
print(p.as_posix())
```

this will print correctly as

```
/dir/wnotherdir/joodir/more
```

but for different other string path, it acts weirdly. Ex, for the string,

```
'\dir\aotherdir\oodir\more'
```

it correctly replacing backslashes but the value is wrong because of the character 'a' in original string

```
/dir/x07otherdir/oodir/more
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: `\a` is widely interpreted as the ascii BEL character (07), so it looks like repr(), is performing this translation.  A shallow search suggests you should be using `x = x.replace("\\", "/")` to correct the path separator.

Comment: still getting the same response as /dir/x07otherdir/oodir/more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with paths per-se. The problem here is that the `\a` is being interpreted as an [ASCII BELL](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=bell#string-and-bytes-literals). As a rule of thumb whenever you want to disable the special interpretation of `escaped` string literals you should use [`raw`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=raw%20string#strings) strings:

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> r = r'\dir\aotherdir\oodir\more'
>>> pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r)
PureWindowsPath('/dir/aotherdir/oodir/more')
>>>
```

Comment: this will work. But i need to pass the variable dynamically. That's why a variable is needed here to represent the string path

Comment: @AhkamNaseek the raw-string would be created at the point of input. The string-literal would be ideally be escaped when read if it contains a "\" by all low-level apis, so you wouldn't need to call `repr()` to escape it, eg: 
`
>>> s = input()
\a
>>> with open('foo.txt', 'w') as fd: fd.write(s)
...
2
>>> open('./foo.txt').read()
'\\a'
>>>
`